# Why observable behavior eager when returning it from a rest endpoint?

Tags: observable, rx-java2

```
@GetMapping(value = "/list", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public Observable<List<Person>> allPerson(){
        return Observable
                .range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                .map(this::listAllPerson)
                .takeWhile(list -> !list.isEmpty());
    }
```

The Observables are lazy but when returning an observable from a rest endpoint, for example, in a spring-boot app it behavior eager even without any subscription.

How and why?

This question may look stupid but I don't know and wondering answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a subscription under the hood. The framework (I guess you are using WebFlux) calls the `allPerson()` method when it receives a request, subscribes to the returned Observable and sends the content back to the caller. It all happens asynchronously, so the framework is able to handle multiple requests concurrently.

Comment: Hi @Mafor, I didn't use WebFlux in this example. Besides rxjava, my dependencies spring-starter-web and jpa. I am thinking like you, there is a subscription but I'm not sure this is the default behavior

Comment: Spring MVC behaves similarly in the Spring Boot 2. In previous versions this code wouldn't work at all, you would need to register an additional message converter.

Comment: Hi @Mafor. I looked at Tomasz Nurkiewicz's book, He says "Pay attention to where you see subscribe() in domain code. Often your business logic is just composing Observables all the way down and returning them to some sort of framework or scaffolding layer. The actual subscription happens behind the scenes in a web
framework or some glue code. It is not a bad practice to call subscribe() yourself, but try to push it out as far as possible." Thank you so much

Comment: Righ. As a rule of thumb, the consumer should decide when to subscribe. Otherwise, you would create so-called "hot-observables" which are much harder to manage and lead to all kinds of back-pressure problems.